# Navigation item setVisible

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm going to  set visible Navigation item (true or false) as the some condition.

```
item = (MenuItem)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.find_doctor_nav);mInsertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {if(type.equals("Doctor")){
                    item.setVisible(false);
                }
                if(type.equals("Patient")){
                    item.setVisible(true);
                }
                CharSequence text = "User session start..!";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my piece of code which is i'm going to do this. But this is give me error

> android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference

I'm doing in fragment class but it's not work with my code. Please suggest me some proper solution. Thanks....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should find `NavigationView` and do

```
//Inside Activity

public void setItemVisible(boolean visible){
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    toggleVisibility(navigationView.getMenu(), R.id.find_doctor_nav, visible);
}

private void toggleVisibility(Menu menu, @IdRes int id, boolean visible){
    menu.findItem(id).setVisible(visible);
}
```

You find the item from menu

Edit:

Use an `Interface` and make your activity implement it. Then in your `Fragment`, call `((NavigationMenuListener)getActivity).setItemVisible(true /*or false*/);`

```
public interface NavigationMenuListener {
    void setItemVisible(boolean visible);
}
```

For more, just google on Fragments. There's more answers.

Comment: But you are using Desig Library's `NavigationView`?

Comment: Elvis, this is not work because i'm setting this in "fragment". two days before my code work but this time is not work. I want know to this is a right way to do this, because i'm newer in android

Comment: Yes this android NavigationView. i'm write Navigation code in main activity but i'm do this in fragment

Comment: Make your activity implement `NavigationMenuListener ` and implement `setItemVisible(boolean visible)` and then do the `toggleVisibility(visible)` there. In the Fragment, do as I explained in the first post. This has worked for me, so try and it'll work for you too.